# how to display topic words using sklearn api in gensim

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, gensim, lda

I am trying to perform LDATransformer using gensim api and then I want to get the topic words only using following code:

```
from gensim.sklearn_api.ldamodel import LdaTransformer
   print("Loading docs for lda input...")
   docs = get_lda_input_from_corpus_folder(CORPUS_PATH)
    print("Topic modeling using LdaTransformer..")
    dictionary = Dictionary(docs)
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in docs]
    model =  LdaTransformer(id2word=dictionary, num_topics=n_topics,iterations=lda_n_iter,random_state=n_random)
    model.fit(corpus)
    print("\nTopical words:")
    print("-" * 20)
    topic_word = model.topic_word_
    n_top_words = 8
 for i, topic_dist in enumerate(topic_word):
     topic_words = np.argsort(topic_dist)[:-(n_top_words+1):-1]
     print('Topic {}: {}'.format(i, ' '.join(topic_words)))
```

but when I print these topic words i have received an error as:

```
AttributeError: 'LdaTransformer' object has no attribute 'topic_word_'
```

any other method which I can use to extract words from this model?